# proving that $f(r,\varphi) = \left(\frac{r}{1 - r},\varphi\right)$ is continuous

Tags: general-topology

I am trying to prove that a open disk of radius $1$ is homeomorphic to $\mathbb R^2$. I'm doing the following:

Firstly let's define the disk as:

$$D_1 = \{(r,\varphi):r\in [0,1) \wedge \varphi\in [0,2\pi)\}$$

Using this we can define the following function:

$$f:D_1 \to \Bbb R^2$$
$$f(r,\varphi) = \left(\frac{r}{1 - r},\varphi\right)$$

I proved that this is an bijection but I'm having some trouble proving that this function is continuous. How can I do so?

Comment: It is not... Because it is not well defined in (1,φ)...

Comment: You want the OPEN disk. It should be $r\in [0,1)$

Comment: Thanks, already corrected it @jjagmath

Comment: With this function how will you attain negative numbers,  in order to be onto?

Comment: What do you mean by negative numbers in $\mathbb R^2$? @dmtri

Comment: Like (-1,0)....

Comment: $r/1-r$ is always not negative....

Comment: That's easy. We are using polar coordinates. That point is simply $(1,\pi)$. So we would have that $f(\frac{1}{2},\pi) = (1,\pi)$ which is the same point as $(-1,0)$ @dmtri

Comment: You write in your question that $f$ is bijection, ie onto,  so what the solution of $ f(r,φ)=(-2,0)$ would be for r, φ?

Comment: is $(-2,0)$ already in polar coordinates? If now, the point $(-2,0)$ is simply: $(2,\pi)$. So we would have: $f(\frac{2}{3},\pi)=(2,\pi)$ @dmtri

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function is continuous, but it does not help you. You have $D_1 = [0,1) \times [0,2\pi)$ which is **not** homeomorphic to the open disk $U(0;1)$ of radius $1$.

I suggest to define
$$\phi : U(0;1) \to \mathbb R^2, \phi(x) = \dfrac{x}{1- \lVert x \rVert}.$$
The function $\lVert - \rVert :  \mathbb R^2 \to \mathbb R$ is continuous and the scalar product $s : \mathbb R \times \mathbb R^2, s(t,y) = t \cdot y$, is continuous. Thus $\phi$ is continuous. Simlilarly
$$\psi : \mathbb R^2 \to U(0;1), \psi(y) = \dfrac{y}{1 + \lVert y \rVert}$$
is continuous and it easy to verify that $\psi\circ \phi = id_{U(0;1)}$ and $\phi\circ \psi = id_{\mathbb R^2}$.